# Infile with informat only taking selected columns, not whole table

Tags: sas

I have a column in my table which I would like to convert from numeric to char.

This is my code:

```
data want; 
infile 'file location.csv' truncover dlm = ',' firstobs = 2 dsd; 
informat col $5. col; 
input col; 
Run;
```

However, this only gives me a single column (the column col which was changed). It does not output the rest of the table. I have tried informat + input with the other columns, but it randomly fills blank cells with numbers.

Is there any way to get the entire table with only one column augmented?

Comment: Huh?  You are only reading one column in your INPUT statement. How is SAS going to know to read other columns if you don't tell it? Please post an example of two or three records of the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

To read in a file with a data step, you have to write everything yourself, indeed

```
data want; 
    infile 'file location.csv' truncover dlm = ',' firstobs = 2 dsd; 
    informat col1 col2 col3 col4 $5.; 
    input col1 $ col2 $ col3 $ col4 $; /* not sure if you need the dollars here */
Run;
```

You can have code of that kind generated for you with `proc import`:

```
proc import datafile='file location.csv'
    out=want dbms=csv replace; 
    getnames=no; 
run;
```

However, this gives little control over the formats.

Alternatively, if you are working in Enterprise guide, you might open the file from the menu of the application. That opens a wizard in which you can tune things like formats.

Comment: Note that $ are NOT needed in list mode input if SAS has already made a determination that the variable is character. Its purpose is prevent SAS from defining the unknown variable that is first referenced in the INPUT statement as numeric. The INFORMAT statement before the INPUT statement will have the side effect of forcing SAS to pick a type for the variable in addition to attaching the informat..